# Hacking - Memorize a command before reimplement it

Tags: macros

Here is a small code.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{menukeys}

\begin{document}

\keys{Ctrl+Alt+C}
\keys{BUG}
\keys{\return}

\end{document}
```

Let's supposed that I know for example that `\keys{BUG}` and `\keys{\return}` don't work well. So I would like to redefine the commands `\keys` so as to use a partial home made solution during that the package will be repaired.

To do that I need to keep the trace of the original `\keys` macro in a command `\@@@@keys` for example. Then I could define my macro `\keys` that will take care of the arguments `BUG` and `\return`, or just reuse the original macro `\keys`. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this, however I did not check how `\keys` processes its input, I notice that it is not defined as a one parameter macro initially, it could do things with catcodes which here will not be possible. Perhaps though this does not happen, hence the proposed solution could be viable.

> [image: my keys]

(`standalone` class used to produce cropped image)

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{menukeys}

\makeatletter
\let\originalkeys\keys
%\show\keys
\protected\def\keys #1{\in@{#1}{BUG,\return}%
                        \ifin@\expandafter\mykeys\else
                              \expandafter\originalkeys
                        \fi {#1}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\mykeys}[1]{\fbox{\ttfamily\detokenize{#1}}}
\begin{document}
  \keys{Ctrl+Alt+C} 
  \keys{BUG} 
  \keys{\return}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good. I will keep that in my recipes. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @projetmbc de rien. But in case `\keys` accepts an optional parameter, let me mention that the method here does not allow its use here with the patched version.

Comment: The method only work for no-optional-argument macros ?

Comment: it works even for a macro with an optional argument as long as no use is made of an optional argument ... if you need to patch a macro with optional argument this can be done too.

Comment: Cool. I will keep it in mind.